# TinyMCE only loads on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using Tinymce-Rails with Ruby on Rails and trying to figure out why the TinyMCE text editor boxes aren't working unless I refresh the page.

So I've followed all the documentation for getting it to work... but the only problem is that it only works after I refresh the page for the first time. Here's the javascript that's responsible for initializing TinyMCE

```
var ready;

ready = function(){
  tinyMCE.init({
    selector: "textarea.tinymce",
    toolbar: ["styleselect | undo redo | bold italic underline | bullist | outdent indent"],
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    style_formats: [{"title":"Headers","items":[{"title":"Header 1","format":"h1"},{"title":"Header 2","format":"h2"},{"title":"Header 3","format":"h3"}]},{"title":"Inline","items":[{"title":"Bold","icon":"bold","format":"bold"},{"title":"Italic","icon":"italic","format":"italic"},{"title":"Underline","icon":"underline","format":"underline"},{"title":"Code","icon":"code","format":"code"}]}],
    content_css: "/assets/tinymce.css"
  });

};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Does anyone know why this isn't actually working when I browse to the page for the first time, but only works for the second time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I stumbled upon your question since I had the same issue. After spending around an hour, I found out that turbolinks was the one causing the problem. From official [github](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks), I quote:

> Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS
>   between each page change, it keeps the current page instance alive and
>   replaces only the body and the title in the head

I cannot tell the exact reason but it indeed had an effect.

To disable turbolinks, I followed this [link](http://blog.flightswithfriends.com/post/53943440505/how-to-disable-turbolinks-in-rails-4)

> 1) Remove “gem “turbolinks”” from your Gemfile and run bundle.
>
> 2) Remove “//= require turbolinks” from application.js.
>
> 3) Remove any “data-turbolinks-track” attributes in your layouts.

Comment: I am having the same problem but I already disabled turbolinks, but still tinyMCE will not load the first time, only after a refresh? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't make it work by disabling `turbolinks` or with the `event listener`
so the solution I found, in serendipity, was adding

```js
tinymce.remove()
```

and I had console errors because `content` and `skins`

```js
skin: false,
content_css: false
```

My example code:

```
import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce'
import 'tinymce/plugins/table';
import 'tinymce/plugins/lists';
import 'tinymce/themes/silver/theme'
import 'tinymce/icons/default/icons'
import 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css'
import 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/content.min.css'
import 'tinymce/skins/content/default/content.css'

function tinyMce() {
    tinymce.remove();    
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea#default',  // change this value according to your HTML
        height: 400,
        plugin: 'a_tinymce_plugin',
        a_plugin_option: true,
        a_configuration_option: 400,
        skin: false,
        content_css: false
       })}
   
export { tinyMce };
```

Note that I'm using rails 6 and webpacker so your solution might vary

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I solved this by wrapping my TinyMCE function in an event listener. This way I don't have to disable turbo links completely, because yeah, I like it.

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '.tinymce',
    height: 500,
    skin: false,
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
      'wordcount'
    ],
    toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | ' +
      'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
      'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
      ' removeformat'
  });
});
```